# i have a problem with saving data to database using LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, laravel

this is all my codes after cliking on button doesn't save to database i try to change method of saving but not work

```
    use App\makereservations;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class reservationController extends Controller
{
    public function hreservation()
    {
        return view('hreservation');
    }
    public function reserve (Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request ,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|email',
            'date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',

        ]);
        $reservation  = new makereservations();
        $reservation  =  $request->input('name');
        $reservation  =  $request->input('email');
        $reservation  =  $request->input('phone');
        $reservation  =  $request->input('date');
        $reservation  =  $request->input('time');
        $reservation  =  $request->input('personne');
        $reservation -> statu =  false;
        $reservation -> save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

this is the roote 
route::post('reserve',  'reservationController@reserve' )->name('reserv.sent');

Comment: what is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it more shortly and in a clean way, to optimize your code.**

```
public function reserve (Request $request)
{
    $attributes = $this->validate($request ,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'personne' => ''
    ]);

    $attributes['statu'] = false;

    makereservations::create($attributes);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**In your model make sure these things**

```
class makereservations extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reservation';
    protected $guarded = []; //it means all data from request will be mass assignable
}
```

Comment: I tried but show me this message and the table name reservation if
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'restau_app.makereservations' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `makereservations` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `date`, `time`, `personne`, `statu`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, testtest@gmail.com, 12345678, 5/7/2020, 12:30am, 1, 0, 2020-05-31 17:33:40, 2020-05-31 17:33:40))

Comment: i changed name of table but does'nt work how i can make old table works 


$inputs = $request->all();

        $inputs['statu'] = false;

        $reservation = reservation::create($inputs);  <=========== focus here

        return redirect()->back();

Comment: can you tell me what is your table name in mysql and what is your model name for that table ? And you don't need to change your table name, look very simple, you have a table name `reservation` and you might have made a model for this table named `makereservations`, right ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `contacts` (`name`, `email`, `subject`, `message`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, test@gmail.com, mytest, text text text text, 0, 2020-06-01 19:54:14, 2020-06-01 19:54:14))

Comment: So you are having problem in another table now ?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `->` arrow sign.

```
$reservation  = new makereservations();
$reservation->name  =  $request->input('name');
$reservation->email  =  $request->input('email');
$reservation->phone  =  $request->input('phone');
$reservation->date  =  $request->input('date');
$reservation->time  =  $request->input('time');
$reservation->personne  =  $request->input('personne');
$reservation-> statu =  false;
$reservation-> save();
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: i changed name of table but does'nt work how i can make old table works 


$inputs = $request->all();

        $inputs['statu'] = false;

        $reservation = reservation::create($inputs);  <=========== focus here

        return redirect()->back();

Comment: In your reservation table, add this line, `protected $table = 'new_table_name';` Now, reservation::create() will save in your new table.

Answer (score 1):

If in the MakeReservations model you have massively assignable fields

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class makereservations extends Model
{
    protected $table = "your_table_name"
    ...
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'phone', 'date', 'time', 'personne', 'status'
    ];
    ...
}
```

Your reserve method in reservationController it may be so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\makereservations;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class reservationController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function reserve (Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request ,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',

        ]);
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $inputs['status'] = false;
        $reservation = makereservations::create($inputs);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I have detected that in your validation method you are trying to validate that the phone is an email

Comment: do i must create new table with the name makereservations becouse i allready have table named reservation

Comment: i changed name of table but does'nt work how i can make old table works 


$inputs = $request->all();

        $inputs['statu'] = false;

        $reservation = reservation::create($inputs);  <=========== focus here

        return redirect()->back();

Comment: Oh yes, varname is statu, you must change it in $fillable array in your model